# Deploying access database to program files without Read only warnings?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an access database which I've deployed to user's computers. The database is a front end with linked tables to an SQL server database. However, I'd like to deploy the database to the user's Program files directory if possible, as this makes deployment of new versions easier (rather than keeping it somewhere in users' profiles). However, as this is a read-only location, it would give the user the read only warning banner, which I don't want.

Also, is there a way to distribute updates to the front end easier?

Comment: Have you tried putting the front-end into a standard user-writable location that you can specify using environment variables: `%USERPROFILE%`, `%APPDATA%`, or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` for an individual user, or perhaps `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` for all users on a given machine? That's normally where application files go when they need to be updateable because `%ProgramFiles%` is read-only for normal users (as you have noticed).

Comment: @GordThompson, the thing is, I don't need it to be writeable.

Comment: Normally you do. Access expects to be able to update the state of various UI objects as the user works with the front-end. That requires write access to the front-end file.